# How to prove emprical risk converges to expectation risk as $n\to \infty$?

Tags: limits-and-convergence, machine-learning, expectation

For example, for a classical binary classification:
$x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $y \in\{0,1\}$
let empirical risk be
$R_{\ell}^n(f):=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \ell\left(f\left(X_i\right), Y_i\right)$
and expectation risk is  $R_{\ell}(f):=\mathbb{E}_{(X, Y) \sim \rho}[\ell(f(X), Y)]$.
Here, $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of binary classifiers with finite $\mathrm{VC}$ dimension, $\rho$ is a distribution over $\mathbb{R}^d \times\{0,1\}$, and $\left(X_1, Y_1\right), \ldots,\left(X_n, Y_n\right)$ is i.i.d. samples from $\rho$.
Let the loss function be:
$\ell(0,0)=\ell(1,1)=0, \quad \ell(1,0)=1 / 2, \quad \ell(0,1)=1$
$f_n^*$ is the minimizer of $R_{\ell}^n$ over $f \in \mathcal{F}$ and  $f^*$ is the minimizer of $R_{\ell}$ over $f \in \mathcal{F}$
In this situation, I have no idea how to prove with probability one that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|R_{\ell}\left(f_n^*\right)-R_{\ell}\left(f^*\right)\right|=0$ exactly.
It also seems that this result is not dependent on whether the loss function is the 0-1 loss or not. Why?

Thanks!